# Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'JSON'

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json, xcode7.3, swift2

Below is the code,

```
//Controller.swift
struct MyObject {
    init(myJson: JSON) {
    // some code here
    }
}

//unittest.swift
let json = JSON("{}")
let obj = MyObject(myJson: json)
```

I get the error `Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'JSON'`

Note: However, this does not happen when I put the struct in the same unit test file. Using SwiftyJSON library for JSON parsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After banging my head for several hours found out that issue was due to including SwiftyJSON file for both app and test targets.

Answer (score 10):

I got this error when I forgot to convert from JSON to Swift representation of the data type. Hope this example helps.

For example:

`let someString = json["name"].string
let someArray = json["products"].arrayObject`